# How to bundle a shared .js file?

Tags: webpack

I have two bundles (`a.js` and `b.js`) that both share state in `c.js`. So both `a.js` and `b.js`do a `c = require('c.js')`, but the variables in `c.js` are not shared between `a.js` and `b.js`.

How do I bundle things so both `a.js` and `b.js` can access the shared state in `c.js`? I

Comment: Make them use an instance from c that would not change the state of the other module. ie. make a class in c that's instantiated in both a and b

Comment: Then you can simply require c